# Chicago-style punctuation in references with tex4ht and biblatex-chicago

Tags: punctuation, babel, tex4ht, biblatex-chicago

The package `biblatex-chicago` moves trailing punctuation inside closing quotation marks in bibliographic notes.

But when using `tex4ht` to convert to ODT format, the punctuation remains outside the quotation marks.

**How do I preserve Chicago-style punctuation when converting to ODT?**

Compile this (`file.tex`) with `latex file && biber file && mk4ht oolatex file`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{screed,
  title={Unhappy Endings: Why Punctuation Should Be Inside Quotation Marks},
  shorttitle={Unhappy Endings},
  author={Manual, Chicago},
  journaltitle={Fussy Punctuators},
  volume=29,
  number=3,
  pages={131--132}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Cite this article.\autocite{screed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this still the case with the newest versions?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is some interference between tex4ht, Babel and BibLaTeX which cause that punctuation rules for US English aren't applied. The following configuration file, `biblatex-chicago.4ht` will load the rules explicitly:

```
\blx@defbibextras{english}{\uspunctuation}
\endinput
```

I would also use the `make4ht` ODT output instead of `mk4ht` oolatex. It fixes some issues regarding the document validation and it enables to call Biber directly during the compilation. Save the following file as `mybuild.mk4`:

```lua
Make:add("biber", "biber ${input}")

if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex{}
else
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

Compile using

```
make4ht -f odt -e mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

The subsequent compilations can be speed up using the draft mode:

```
make4ht -f odt -e mybuild.mk4 -m draft filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]